# How can I compare the datetime of argument with Today's date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Now I'm trying to make helper method like this.
How can I compare the datetime of argument with Today's date?

```
def todate_datetime(date_time)
    date_time = Date.today ? "<font color='red'>#{date_time}</font>" : date_time
end
```

**UPDATE:**

**view**

> <%= today_datetime(community_topic.updated_at) %>

**helpers**

```
def today_datetime(date_time)
  date_time == Date.today ? "<font color='red'>#{date_time.to_s(:ct)}</font>" : date_time.to_s(:ct)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from ruby 1.9.2 you can directly compare a DateTime object with a Date object in ruby, e.g. try in irb:

```
require 'date'
today = DateTime.new(2013,1,4)
 => #<DateTime: 2013-01-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456297j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
today == Date.today
=> true
```

However, Rails has its own DateTime object ([APIdock Rails DateTime](http://apidock.com/rails/DateTime)). One option is to convert the Rails Object to a date via the `to_date` method

So then the helper method could look like this:

```
def todate_datetime(date_time)
  date_time.to_date == Date.today ? "<font color='red'>#{date_time}</font>" : date_time
end
```

**EDIT**: it might be more accurate to compare the `date_time` argument to `DateTime.current.to_date` since that takes the `config.time_zone` into account if set:

```
def todate_datetime(date_time)
  date_time.to_date == DateTime.current.to_date ? "<font color='red'>#{date_time}</font>" : date_time
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your code but it returns just **:date_time** even if it's today for sure. I updated my question. could you please check that?

Comment: Thanks. I made another update. The edited solution might be more accurate, if you're dealing with time zones in your app.